# Find most recent date

Tags: postgresql, date, difference

I have o table name table_1 with 4 columns `id`, `text`, `fromDate`, `toDate`. The table represents the working experience.I want to create a function which will return the row with columns `id`, `text` where the employee worked more recently. This means I need column `toDate` to be closest to today.

Here is a demonstration of my code:

```
Select (abs("toDate"-now())) as date_diff
from table_1

Select id,text
from table_1
where (abs("toDate"-now()))=select min(date_diff)
```

Is this correct or is there something better I can do?

Comment: Does your data store information about the future?  Are you sure you don't need "current information where duration period (fromDate to toDate) includes today or nearest date when it doesn't"?  That would mean looking for the maximum toDate before today, or the minimum fromDate after today?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wil try something like this:

```
Select id,text
from table_1
where "toDate" = ( select max ("toDate") from  table_1 )
```

It will provide you the latest "toDate" value.

Comment: This will show you all the results if there are more than one rows mathcing the maximum "toDate"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select * from table_1
order by to_date desc
limit 1
```